# Why CodeIgniter Pagination Link Bloats?

Tags: .htaccess, routes, pagination, codeigniter-2

I have spent some time but can't figure out what's wrong. I am using CodeIgniter 2.1.0.

So basically its like this:

My pagination settings:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . '/stores/';
$config['total_rows'] = $this->stores_model->getTotalRows();
$config['per_page'] = 20; //display 20 rows per page
$config['num_links'] = 10; //display 10 pagination links
$config['uri_segment'] = 2;
$config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
$config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

I am getting data chunks like this from controller. Which is also working.

```
$data['stores'] = $this->stores_model->getChunks($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(2));
```

My view page have:

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

Now everything is working fine. At first the 10 pagination links are shown but when I click on the link 8, 9 or 10 etc. the pagination links bloats. It shows now links 1 to 20. Why is that? It might be something very simple but can't seem to figure that out. I was expecting the pagination links kind of scroll but shows only 10 links as I have set in config.

Thanks and regards

Deepak

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand

$config['num_links'] got me confused for a while.

This means the number of links to show on both sides (previous and next) of current link.

```
ie. (show prev 10 links from current) <----- [current page] -----> (show next 10 links from current)
```

setting it to 5 solved the problem. Now I have about 11 links showing in total all the time as expected.

Thanks again

Deepak